# How to translate this SQL query with propel?

Tags: symfony1, propel

i don't know how to  translate this query :

```
SELECT distinct(id_ville) FROM `point_location`
```

I try to do it, but it doesn't work :

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(PointLocationPeer::ID_VILLE, Criteria::DISTINCT);
$c->setDistinct();
$this->villes = PointLocationPeer::doSelect($c);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->addSelectColumn(PointLocationPeer::ID_VILLE);
$c->setDistinct();
$this->villes = PointLocationPeer::doSelect($c);
```